# How to install Oxford Advanced Learners' 8 in ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, dictionary

I have bought Oxford Advanced Learners' 8 which come along with installation CD. In the cd they have linux installation option. But i can't install that in my ubuntu.
When i run setup.sh from my terminal i get the following error message:

```
The setup program seems to have failed on AMD64/unknown
Fatal error, no tech support email configured in this setup
```

Does anyone have idea about installing OALD 8 in Ubuntu x64?

Comment: You can use it with **Stardict**. Run `sudo apt-get install stardict` to install stardict. Then copy and paste dictionary file from the CD to /usr/share/stardict/dic folder.

Comment: See this [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1211149) thread. It seems you need to install `libgtk2.0-0` (for 12.04) and `libcanberra-gtk-module`

Comment: Which file is the dictionary file?

Comment: What are the contents of directory from which you are trying to install it. List all the files. It is necessary to know the file type!!

Answer (score 2):

For OALD8 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, try the following instructions:

> **1 Dependencies**
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-sdl dpkg-dev
> ```
>
> **2 Mount the ISO/CD**
>
> using Furious ISO Mount Tool, etc!
>
> **3 Begin Installation**
>
> Go to the mount directory
>
> ```
> cd linux
>
> linux32 ./setup.sh
> ```
>
> **Tweaks:**
>
> **1**
>
> No Sound?
>
> Try padsp – PulseAudio OSS Wrapper:
>
> padsp starts the specified program and redirects its access to OSS
>   compatible audio devices (/dev/dsp and auxiliary devices) to a
>   PulseAudio sound server.
>
> ```
> padsp path-to-the-oald8
> ```
>
> eg:
>
> ```
> padsp ‘/home/nikunj/oald8/oald8′
> ```
>
> **2**
>
> Create a Shell-Script on the Desktop
>
> ```
>  #!/bin/sh
>
>  padsp ‘/home/nikunj/oald8/oald8′
> ```
>
> Make it executable. Also, optionally set the ICON from:
>   `/home/nikunj/oald8/chrome/icons/default/main-window.xpm`
>
> **3 (adjust)**
>
> Annoying Dialog: Click OK to download Plugin
>
> Click Cancel. Yeah! Adjust! :P

[Original tutorial by Nikunj Lahoti.](https://nikunjlahoti.wordpress.com/tag/install-oald8-on-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.