# How can I get the sound output in Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary 8 working?

Tags: 64-bit, 14.04, dictionary

I'm trying to install OALD8 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. These are the steps I took so far:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk ia32-libs-sdl dpkg-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-gtk
E: Unable to locate package ia32-libs-sdl

$ padsp '/home/ioannis/oald8/oald8' 
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
/home/ioannis/oald8/oald8-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libpangoxft-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

---

Following these error messages I installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
```

Now the OALD8 starts but I cannot hear pronunciation sounds.

This is the command line output I see:

```
$ padsp '/home/ioannis/oald8/oald8' 
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
LoadPlugin: failed to initialize shared library /home/ioannis/oald8/plugins/libflashplayer.so [libnssutil3.so.1d: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
LoadPlugin: failed to initialize shared library /home/ioannis/oald8/plugins/libflashplayer.so [libnssutil3.so.1d: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory]
```

Thanks in advance for any effort and time

Comment: Just for reference: You installed OALD8 by following the steps in [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/374754/how-to-install-oxford-advanced-learners-8-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts-64bit), right? This particular application seems to have quite a lot of issues on Linux. I can't help you with getting it work but what I can do is suggest an alternative: [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/). It supports a multitude of different dictionary formats including Babylon and StarDict, which can easily be found on the web.

Comment: Pronounciations are also supported (either via audio data built into the dictionary or [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/)).

Comment: Basically you are right I installed the OALD8 by following the steps in you are refer but I also run some lines of code from some other threads in ask_ubuntu. If I don't manage to make OALD8 run properly I'll install it with wine. I did it in the past but runs a bit slow. I'm sorry for the bad use of the english language

Comment: I am currently learning it. I am taking the exam for the levels B1-B2 at the beginning of May.

Comment: No need to be sorry, your English is absolutely fine . I hope you will be able to find a solution for these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue (I replied another thread about this [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491742/how-to-install-oald8-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64)).

This is a flash issue. It is because the flash library asks for a 32bits version of libnssutil3.so.1d. If you install this one, it will complain about libplc4.so.0d.

These libraries are respectively in the packages libnss3-1d:i386 and libnspr4-0d:i386.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386
```

If, after installing these libraries, you get a "**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**" every time you try to start the dictionary, just remove these packages, or even rename or remove the libflashplayer.so from the ~/oald8/plugins folder.

P.S.: Try to install the *gtk2-engines:i386* (or other gtk2-engine) to cease that Gtk-Messages.

**UPDATE**

[In the other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491742/how-to-install-oald8-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64/492158#492158) I posted a full solution to make the sound and flash to work. I think it will work in your box as well.

I believe you were still experiencing sound issues, even using the padsp wrapper, because the padsp insists to use the 64bits version of the libpulsedsp.so library.

Please, let me know if you succeed to make the sound works.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian and Ubuntu:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp:i386
```

You should now have this path on your system:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/
```

Then

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/padsp /usr/bin/padsp_32
```

Use your favorite text editor (as root!) to edit `padsp_32`. You will change the two places that say

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so
```

to

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so
```

Then just type

```
padsp_32 /your/program/here
```

this was from 
http://www.ideatrash.net/2014/06/fix-padsp-to-use-pulseaudio-on-64-bit.html