# How to install Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 9th on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have a oxford dictionary mdf file.I want to install in ubuntu 16.4. How to install `OALD9` on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/492158/665251 see if this works for you

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh i have a mdf file not iso file.How to install .mdf file

Comment: i also search many time in internet.I am unable to install oald9 in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Even the approach with ISO file is not working perfectly, let me try it as well, i'll post a solution if it works :)

Comment: To open or mount ISO file systems inside MDF archives you can refer to https://askubuntu.com/a/43481/175814.