# Problem with opening Oxford English Dictionary version 8 (OALD8) application in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I have installed Oxford English Dictionary version 8 (OALD8) software in Ubuntu 18.04 but I am unable to launch the software. I had followed the installation procedure as described in the thread [How to Install OALD8 on Ubuntu 14.04 x64?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491742/how-to-install-oald8-on-ubuntu-14-04-x64), but after the step three, that is after making my icon executable I am still not able to launch the application.

Problem:

After clicking my application icon nothing is happening. I tried opening the application via command line using the shell file 'run-oald8.sh', which is inside the installed application folder, and that too is giving me the same result.

I shall describe the steps that i followed for installing the software as follows

1. First I copied the contents of the CD into my system
2. I then executed the setup file using the commands

   ```
   cd linux
   ./setup.data/bin/Linux/x86/setup
   ```
3. Now I installed the packages required for the oald8 libraries to work using the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386 libpangox-1.0-0:i386
   ```
4. After that I installed gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 and gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 using the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
   ```
5. I also installed the atk-bridge package using the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor:i386
   ```
6. Finally I made the desktop icon executable

Now please tell me where did I go wrong or what I should do to make this software work?

Comment: Now I have updated the question a little more clearly, i hope. I tried using the command the launcher uses too but nothing is happening, no errors or notifications or crashes.

Comment: This one is almost the same: https://gist.github.com/masiur/6e09e88cb8bf584bc33d but says to 1st do `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so`  can you install that from the method they provide and try again? :)

Comment: I installed that as well as reinstalled the software by using the command 'linux32 setup.sh'  but i am still getting the same result.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'm a bit unclear on what you are saying. Which installation procedure did you follow? There are 2 answers to the duplicate question that you linked to in your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I have followed the installation procedure having the highest up scores, the one in which you are asked to copy the required folders into your system and then do the installation.